# query_posts by category_name and custom taxonomy

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, query-posts

I want to display posts filtered by category_name and custom taxonomy-term:

I have

```
function channel_init() {
// create a new taxonomy
register_taxonomy(
    'channel',
    'post',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Channel' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'channel' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'capabilities' => array(
            'manage__terms' => 'edit_posts',
            'edit_terms' => 'manage_categories',
            'delete_terms' => 'manage_categories',
            'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts'
        )
    )
);

}
add_action( 'init', 'channel_init' );
```

Imagine i have a channel-term "news". And a catgory_name "music" - Now i want to query:

```
query_posts( array( 'channel' => 'news', 'category_name' => 'music') );
```

channel is ignored category is filtered only.

Comment: Did you try this. query_posts( array( 'channel' => 'channel', 'category_name' => 'music') );.  Because it should be `category name => slug`

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`. Also, you would want to use a `tax_query` to query posts from a custom taxonomy terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'channel',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'news', 'comedy' ), //this is by slug
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ), //this is by id
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

That could be great if you use WP_Query than query_posts. But result are the same. WP_Query is more flexible :). Don't forget to check more in deep about [query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: No, `WP_Query` is not more flexible. `query_posts` uses `WP_Query` to run its query, so none of the two are more flexible than the other. The big difference is, `query_posts` sets the main query object (*`$wp_query`*) to the current custom query. This breaks the main query object which breaks pagination, page functionality, conditional tags, dunctions like related posts and `get_queried_object)`. That is why you should never use `query_posts`

Comment: @PieterGoosen , Thanks for explaination and I will note it.